# How do i stop my webpage from refreshing when i change the style:display of a div in JS?

Tags: javascript, c#, show-hide

This is my piece of code that changes the style.display of my div:

```
if (aBoolean && bBoolean && cBoolean) {
    document.getElementById("SubmitArea").style.display = block;
}
```

When this line of code fires it refreshes my webpage somehow, I dont know if that is suppose to happen or not. If it is how can I prevent it from doing so? And if it isn't what could be the cause of the refreshing?

I am using asp.net with C#.

Comment: Something else is refreshing your page, please post more code so we can check it out.

Comment: it must be something else that's causing the refresh. unless `block` represents some other weird object causing it. shouldn't it be `...display = "block"`?

Comment: This line in and of itself is not enough to cause the refresh. We need more code, or more context about this page.

Comment: Is this code called from a link `onclick` or using the DOM `click` event?  As others have said, this code itself isn't causing the refresh, but potentially how this is being called is.

Comment: Are you using a <form/> to handle these changes (onsubmit perhaps)? I am guessing the form is refreshing the page because of an error or you are not stopping the submit but could not be sure without seeing more code.

Comment: `document.getElementById("SubmitArea").style.display = "block";` try this. Add `"` before and after block

Comment: @DLeh was right it was the missing the " ' " changed it to `'block'` and it worked. I kept overlooking that typo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed `block` to `'block'`, this fixed the problem.